# Image button as default button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my application i have an image button and two text boxes in a form. i want to make this image button as default button is there any provision to do like that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that using `Panel`

```
<asp:Panel id="pnl" runat="server" DefaultButton="imagebutton1">

// Some controls and code //

<asp:ImageButton id="imagebutton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/imge.gif" >
</asp:ImageButton>

// Some controls and code //

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: @ Harsh: Thanks for the reply is it necessary to put all other controls in the same panel in the web page.. because i just inserted the imagebutton in the panel and its not working for me when i press enter key

Comment: @Mathew can you share some of the rest of your code? Are you using MasterPages?

Comment: @Mathew you need to include the controls in the panel on click of which u want image button to be defaultbutton

Comment: Yes got it by giving the panel for all the controls in my web page thank you.. for faster execution javascript is also available..

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one in form tag:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultfocus="imagebutton1">
```